# Find all primitive roots $n=2\cdot11^{2016}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all primitive roots $n=2\cdot11^{2016}$

I know a primitive root exists because it is in the form $2p^k$

Therefore we only need to find a primitive root $a$ of $n$ and then all the primitive roots are $a^k$ such that $gcd(k, \varphi(n)) = 1$.

My problem is there doesn't exist any algorithm to find a primitive root so I would have to check a lot of numbers which seems inefficient. Am I missing a trick with this particular number that might allow me to find a primitive root easier?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finding a primitive root modulo a large prime is hard; on the other hand, finding a primitive root modulo $p^k$ or $2p^k$ is easy if you know the primitive roots modulo $p$. The rules (source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n#Finding_primitive_roots)) are:

- If $g$ is a primitive root modulo $p$ and $g^{p-1} \not\equiv 1 \pmod{p^2}$, then $g$ is a primitive root modulo $p^k$ for all $k$.
- If $g$ is a primitive root modulo $p$ and $g^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p^2}$, then $g+p$ is a primitive root modulo $p^k$ for all $k$.
- If $g$ is a primitive root modulo $p^k$, then either $g$ or $g+p^k$ is a primitive root modulo $2p^k$, whichever is odd.

Comment: Oh interesting I must have missed those in my notes. So since $2$ is a primitive root $11^k$ then I could just go straight to the fact that $2+11^{2016}$ is a primitive root for my $n$. Then just write out a few sentences that my other primitive roots will have to satisfy the above condition and I'll have $\varphi(\varphi(n))$ roots.